# how to store product list for an ecommerce android application

Tags: java, android, sqlite

we have a big list of products as an ecommerce store.we are developing an android application for this.We are not having any knowledgeable guy who can guide us on how to store big list of products in sqlite database?Or is there any better way to store big list of products in sqlite database apart from conventional java classes method..
Please guide on this...

Answer (score 0):

SQL-lite database is used to store the small amount of data. In Your case, I would recommend to use the MySql database and store only the small number of products (You can say few latest or featured products) in the sql-lite database. For the other products use pull to refresh library to load more products. Hope it will help.

Comment: yes, ofcourse it is possible and best way to use big data in android application. (According to my knowledge)

Comment: You can use php or asp to get data from mysql database.